# How to check does string contain more than one words?

Tags: javascript

When user searching needs to check query string on this way:

Example:

1. If users type: "Test test" - need to check does query have more then one word
2. And if have, add one more double quotes on "Test test"

Which is the best way for that?

- To check does have any kind of whitespace?

Comment: You can split on white space and then count the length of the array - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: To convert into array and then check?

Comment: If you split by whitespace it will return an array with each word as a separate item so the length of the array will tell you how many words were in your string.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're looking for?

```js
let str = "Test test"
if(str.includes(" ")) {
  str = `"${str}"`
}
```

Or for any kind of whitespace (not just spaces)

```js
if(str.match("\s")) {
  str = `"${str}"`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
str.indexOf(' ') >= 0 ? `"${str}"`: str
```

Comment: The question asks about "any kind of whitespace".

Answer (score 0):

**1. Need to check does query have more than one word :** 
  You can check the space like this:

```
 let string = "Test test"; 
 let count = string.split(" ").length-1 // if count > 1 means more then one word
```

```
  let string = "Test test";
  if(string.includes(" ")){
    // string has space, it means more than one word
  }
```

```
  let string = "Test test";
  let position = string .indexOf(" "); // if space will return position otherwise return -1
```

**2. You can add one more double quotes on "Test test" :** 
 
  You can choose one of the methods to check space, then at the returning place, you can return the

```
 let string = `"${string}"`;
```

**3. if a string contains only whitespace:** 
 
Instead of checking the entire string to see if there's the only whitespace, just check to see if there's at least one character of non-whitespace:

```
let myString = "test Test";
if (/\S/.test(myString)) {
    // if the string is not empty and not having any whitespace
}
```

Comment: interesting way

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this solution. I tried both with `"test Test"` and `"testtest"` and in both cases `/\S/.test(myString)` returned true.

Comment: I mean, how does "there are non-whitespace characters in the string" imply "there's no whitespace character in the string"?